# How to get Array inside fields from JSON Structure in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am beginner in ios and in my project i am integrating services with my app but i am struggling to integrate some service fields with my app

Please see below JSON structure there i want to get all "languages" Array inside  elements but i am not understand how to get those fields please help me some one

### Json stucture:-

```
 - loans: [
                     - {
            id: 983381,
            name: "America",
            description:          {
            languages:          [
            "English"
            ]
            },

        },

         - {
             id: 983382,
            name: "Jarmani",
            description:          {
            languages:          [
            "Jarman"
            ]
            },

        },

     - {
             id: 983383,
            name: "Rasya",
            description:          {
            languages:          [
            "Rasya"
            ]
            },

        },
    ]
```

### my code:-

```
NSMutableArray * array1 = [mainDictyionary objectForKey:@"loans"];

    for (NSDictionary * obj in array1) {

       MainArray = [obj objectForKey:@"languages"];
    }

NSLog(@"so finally  array values are  %@",MainArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to

1. Declare MainArray as a NSMutableArray: `MainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`
2. Now you will be adding the "languages" NSArrays to a 'mother-array', I'm guessing that is not what you want
3. So you want to iterate over the `[obj objectForKey:@"languages"]` array and call `addObject` on the MainArray for every NSString value you'll encounter in the `[obj objectForKey:@"languages"]`-iteration.
4. You'll end up with a mutable NSArray that has all the languages in it, as NSStrings

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are getting the value upto languages and not upto "english" or anyother. And also you are assigning the values to `MainArray`, so it will not add all the values it will add last value of the loop.

```
NSMutableArray * array1 = [mainDictyionary objectForKey:@"loans"];

NSMutableArray *MainArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary * obj in array1) {
       NSDictionary *descriptionDictionary = [obj objectForKey:@"description"];
       [MainArray addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"languages"]];
    }

  NSLog(@"so finally  array values are  %@", MainArray);
```

Comment: how is it's working here languages array is inside Description dectionary please see

Comment: only Rasya element is printing not priting all elements

Comment: updated. I just made a mistake with mainarray and langarray. try now